# Stressing disk for unspecified period of time

Tags: linux, caching, linux-device-driver, disk, dd

Is there a way using dd to stress the disk for an indeterminate period of time? I want to avoid using the cache and maximize the amount of time that is spent either reading or writing to disk. I am currently using the below command:

```
while true: do dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile bs=1048576 count=1024 && sync testfile
```

My concern is that if I continually read from the same file, then it will be stored in the buffer cache therefore leading to inconsistent reads. Thus my intention with this command was to minimize the amount of time reading from /dev/zero and maximizing the amount of time spent syncing the output file to disk. Additionally, I don't want to interfere with other applications running so I don't want to flush the entire cache, just the testfile.